# Access development VM (Vagrant / VirtualBox) from Android phone

Tags: nginx, squid, vagrant

I'm developing a web app on my PC. My dev environment is Vagrant / Virtual Box / Ubuntu 14.4. Vagrant serves the app content on `10.0.0.101`, which is mapped in my hosts file to `dev.myapp.com`. Inside Vagrant, nginx rewrites that to `https://dev.myapp.com`. I would like to access `https://dev.myapp.com` from my Android phone.

I don't have much of a background in networking, so my apologies if some of the following looks ridiculous.

The things I've tried so far:

- Created an ad-hoc network on my host machine and connected to it with my phone, turning off all other connections. I was able to access the Internet, but not the VM IP or the `dev.myapp.com`.
- Used Squid. I *think* the process was supposed to be: Vagrant serves files, Squid forwards requests to localhost to Vagrant, phone configured over Chrome to hit Squid's port on localhost, phone receives files from Vagrant through Squid and Chrome. However, I wasn't able to get Squid to show my server. I assume that hitting `localhost:3130` (as per my config, see below) should have resulted in me seeing the app served by Vagrant. This, however, did not happen.
- Followed [this guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2287494) to reverse-tether my phone to my host computer. Could not do this, received a timeout error on the DHCP step.

**Is there an easy way to do this?** I've spent half the day trying to get this to work, with little to show for it.

The lines I changed in Squid from default config:

```
https_port 3130 transparent cert=/var/certs/myapp.pem key=/var/certs/myapp.key
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 10.0.0.101 ::1
```

Here's my full Squid config:

```
#
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 10.0.0.101 ::1

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
#http_port 3128
https_port 3130 transparent cert=/var/certs/beta.eclips/full.beta.addtrust.domainval.pem key=/var/certs/beta.eclips/beta.key

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
#cache_dir ufs /var/cache/squid 100 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/cache/squid

#
# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
#
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
```